# jQuery Tabbed UI using AJAX - switching between tabs previous view

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Let's say I have two tabs tabA and tabB.  When I click on tabA the first page of that section appears, call it tabA1.  If I click on a link on that page then page tabA1 is replaced with tabA2.  If I then click on another tab, say tabB, and then go and click on tabA again I get an image of tabA2 lingering for a bit.

How can I make it so that clicking tabA will always show tabA1 straight away?  Is it saving it in the cookies for fast access?

Answer (score 0):

Before switching additionally try setting the content in the tab (or equivalent wrapper) to `display : none`.

This is happened to me and that's how I fixed it. Although I know it fixes the symptoms and not the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response Robin - where exactly would the display: none?

Comment: @user1058210: In a callback during the tab `select` event maybe?